# WSL - When I'm not in the C: drive, bash takes me to the home directory

Tags: windows, debian, truecrypt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL with Debian on my Windows 10.

I have a Truecrypt partition mounted on H:

In powershell, if I'm on C: drive and I call bash, I stay in the same directory:

```
PS C:\> bash
admsrv@desktop:/mnt/c$ pwd
/mnt/c
```

But if I'm on the H: drive, bash takes me to the home directory:

```
PS H:\> bash
admsrv@desktop:~$ pwd
/home/admsrv
```

I want bash to leave me in the current directory, whatever it is.

How can I do that?

PS: there is no "cd" instruction in my ~/.bashrc and H: is correctly mounted

```
admsrv@desktop:~$ mount -l
rootfs on / type lxfs (rw,noatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noatime)
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
H: on /mnt/h type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

Thank you

Comment: This is a valid bug. As a user we can't do anything. Here are two same issues https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2315 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/530. Wait for 1-2 years to be fixed ;)